# import twice when run test

Tags: django, testing, import

i have this code in my tests.py:

```
from models import *
```

and in the models.py I have a signal handler and register it with

```
post_save.connect( post_save_note, sender=Note )
```

and when i run test with  `./manage.py test main`

I found the signal handler was registered twice and executed twice,
and I found it's because the models was imported twice.

can't i put `from models import *` in the test code?
what should i do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure your models are always imported the same way.

So for example, if you have in `example1/tests.py`:

```
from models import *
```

and in another package `example2/views.py`:

```
from example1.models import ModelA
```

then you'll have the problem you are experiencing.  The solution is to be consistent and use only one or the other.