# Why is post_save being raised twice during the save of a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, signals

I am attaching a method to the post_save signal of my Django model. This way I can clear some cached items whenever the model is modified.

The problem I am having is that the signal is being triggered twice when the model is saved. It doesn't necessarily hurt anything (the code will just gracefully error out) but it can't be right.

A quick example, just printing the model to the console (using the dev server):

```
from blog.models import Post
from django.db.models import signals

def purge_cache(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'Purging %s' % sender

signals.post_save.connect(purge_cache, sender=Post)
```

This is using the stable 1.1.1 release of Django.

*Updated Information:*

With feedback from everyone's comments, I have modified my question because the issue is now discovering why the post_save is being triggered twice. My guess at the moment is that my models.py code is imported twice and that the post_save is getting connected multiple times.

**What would be the best way to figure out why it is being imported/ran twice?**

Comment: If you comment out the `post_delete` connect line, is the `post_save` signal raised twice ?

Comment: looking at django code and it really does not send in save(), are you sure you're getting post_delete signal and not post_save twice?

Comment: @Desintegr - I can't try it at the moment but that's a good idea. I will try it tonight and update the question. If it still occurs after removing the post_delete though, I'll just change my question to "Why is the post_save signal getting raised twice?" :) Maybe the models.py code is being run twice and the signal is being connected multiple times?

Comment: yeah models.py could be imported a couple of times, on your own imports for example. It's a common problem i think :)

Comment: @Dmitry & Desintegr - I think you both are right. Removing the post_delete still triggers the purge twice. I've changed the question to match the new problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently, [Python is sensitive to the way you import modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801249/import-twice-when-run-test). In my case, it wasn't an issue with any of import code inside my blog application but an issue with the INSTALLED_APPS configuration, which I assume is used by Django to do an initial import.

Inside my blog application I was using imports such as:

```
from blog.models import *
```

My settings.py was configured as:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...snip...
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'mysite.blog',
)
```

The "mysite" prefix was added because I originally had import path issues when deploying the site. Later I fixed this issue (so it acted the same as the development server) by adding multiple paths in my WSGI script.

Removing the "mysite" prefix from the settings.py fixed the issue:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...snip...
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'blog',
)
```

Answer (score 9):

While looking for the root of this problem, you can use quick workaround to prevent registering signal twice:

```
signals.post_save.connect(my_handler, MyModel, dispatch_uid="path.to.this.module")
```

[Source](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Signals#Helppost_saveseemstobeemittedtwiceforeachsave).

Comment: I had seen this but it really seems like a hack they added because people couldn't be bothered to fix their imports. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I think I disagree with @LanceMcNearney above. Suppose you're writing library code.  You can't control the way in which consumers import your code.

Comment: Well django is known for its backwards compatibility, this solution allows newer versions to avoid the issue and still preserves older versions behavior

Comment: I also disagree with @LanceMcNearney above.  In my case the test runner from v1.6 was causing the issue (Was not an issue in 1.5, even though I was using the DiscoverTestRunner there too).  dispatch_uid seems the better way to go.

Comment: This doesn't help for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ticket about this issue: [Django's signal framework may register listeners more than once #3951](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3951). It is now fixed in SVN version of Django.

The problem is exactly as You said: Your module which registers signal, is loaded couple of times, in some cases by different import paths, thus each imported modules this way are wrongly interpreted by Django as different modules which registers the same signal.

Comment: I still have this problem with django 1.6. Providing a dispatch_uid doesn't help.