# Removing the mysite prefix from INSTALLED_APPS in "mysite.app" prevents double imports, why?

Tags: python, django

I ran into the issue where `post_save` was being called twice for no apparent reason. It now seems that the cause was a double import as described here: [Why is post_save being raised twice during the save of a Django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345400/why-is-post-save-being-raised-twice-during-the-save-of-a-django-model) the accept answer suggest removing the `mysite` portion of `mysite.foo` which worked, but why does it do a double import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3951) is caused by mixing import paths in Python. Take the following structure w/ `proj` findable in `sys.path`, for example.

```
proj/
   __init__.py
   app/
       __init__.py
       foo.py

# In proj directory, enter Python shell
>>> import sys

>>> before = set(sys.modules)
>>> import app.foo
>>> set(sys.modules) - before
set(['app', 'app.foo'])

>>> before = set(sys.modules)
>>> from proj.app import foo
>>> set(sys.modules) - before
set(['proj.app.foo', 'proj', 'proj.app'])
```

Python actually treats `proj.app.foo` and `app.foo` as different modules. You could find that `app/__init__.py` and `app/foo.py` get imported twice, thus anything in them actually get executed twice. To fix this, we should use consistent import path: either from `proj` level or from `../proj` level.  In the link you posted, `'mysite.blog'` is fine *AS LONG AS* there is no other importing like `import blog` in the project or Django files.

In Django 1.4, the issue is mostly solved by [moving manage.py one directory up from project directory to its parent directory which is no longer a package, thus limit importing to `proj` level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py).

Also you could [prevent duplicate signals by using `dispatch_uid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals)