# IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/add/ using UserProfile

Tags: django, django-admin, user-profile

I`m tryng to add user from Admin interface, using a UserProfile, but show me this error:

IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/add/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '7' for key 'user_id'")

Here is my UserProfile class:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Other fields here
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(cliente, null=True, blank=True)
    setor = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Setor',
                             max_length=1,
                             default='C',
                             choices=Setor_CHOICE)


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

I try to use this:

```
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, dispatch_uid='user_id')
```

but same error.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it is trying to create a second instance of UserProfile connected to the same User. This can happen if post_save signal gets fired twice.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2345967) points out, this can happen as a result of the order of model imports.